# Unable to run Flask app with gevent installed

Tags: python, flask, websocket, gevent, flask-socketio

I have a Flask application that won't run when gevent is installed.

Here is my app.py file:

```
from app import create_app, socketio

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

**init**.py (with create_app)

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
...

socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')

    ...

    return app
```

When I run `python app.py`, this is what shows in terminal:

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 189-464-699
```

With this running, my application (localhost:5000/) will not load any page- it just says `Internal Server Error`, even if it's not a page that uses websocket. I don't see any requests in terminal as I usually would.

What I expect when I run `python app.py`

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 335-570-116
```

and of course I expect to be able to load site pages.

If I uninstall gevent, I can get the expected behavior, however, I get this error:
`WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.`

`simple-websocket` is already installed. I took this error to mean I should install `gevent` and `gevent-websocket`.

With gevent **uninstalled**, I can load pages, but I receive the above `transport not available` error in the terminal, and the site pages that use websockets have this error in the debugger: `VM78:1 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Ne0kF52 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Sounds like you are launching a process that you want ASYNC but is running SYNC instead.  Nothing in your post indicates gevent.  Unless you were monkey patching before.

Comment: You probably need to monkey patch: http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.monkey.html

Answer (score 0):

for development environment while using socketio.run(app), its better using eventlet.